# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined in Cypress

Tags: parsing, cypress, uncaught-exception

I got the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined" in cypress when I try to bypass/skip forced password change by replacing the URL "https://XXXX.com/login/ForcePasswordChange"  with "https://XXXX.com/home".

Below is the screenshot of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYa9r.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to give us a little more context about what is going on. Post your code and explain what you are trying to do. Maybe also post the data that cause the error when being parsed. If unsure what to do, please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This error is not from Cypress but from your application. Appereantly the application tries to find a value for property `parse`. I guess that property will be filled by the https://XXXX.com/login/ForcePasswordChange. But to be sure you should ask your developer collegue.